# Slow Performance on UIPageViewController Page Turns

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, swift, uipageviewcontroller

This may be a bit unclear but I have no other way to figure this out.

I have a UIPageViewController that displays 5 second mp4 files. Each page has a different video. One of the biggest issues I'm having is that every time I slide to the next page, the slide stalls just before completing its animation. During this stall the video is still loading. Once the video is loaded the slide animation completes.

Looking at the performance, my memory is around 8-9MB. The CPU spikes to 90% when the `UIPageViewController` loads then hovers around 20% afterwards. I went ahead and looked at the View Hierarchy.

**CASE SCENARIO 1**

If I'm on the current page and it just loaded, the `UIPageViewController` has yet to load the next page, and I slide quickly to the right, the animation issue occurs.

**CASE SCENARIO 2**

If I'm on the current page with the video playing and I visit the previous page which `UIPageViewController` still retains, the issue is less likely to occur but can occur. The video is already loaded in this case so I'm not so much inclined to think video loading is the true culprit.

When I run the simulation on my MacBook everything is smooth and I have no issues. It's when I'm testing this on am iPhone 4S that the animation issue occurs. I currently have no way to test this on iPhone 5 and up. I'm wondering if this is strictly a iPhone 4S issue as it is outdated. Any help or explanation as to why this issue occurs and how to fix it would be great.

**UPDATE**

The UIPageViewController is built as so. There is one UIPageViewController and each page represents an individual page view controller. Within each individual page view controller, I create a video player controller using [PBJ Video Player](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVideoPlayer). The PBJ Video Player loads the video from a video URL. The video URL comes from an array.

Looking at this setup, I'm wondering if I should simply replace the individual page view controller with the video player controller.

Comment: well how are you loading each video? is it just by index or are they separate ViewControllers or?

Comment: Is it a stream? If not, are you sure PBJVideoPlayer is accessing the url on the background thread?
What do you exactly do when you visit a new page (i mean resource allocation)? like, what you load?

Comment: I don't know the inter-workings of the PBJVideoPlayer. All I can say is this. When I visit a new page, I load up a new VideoPlayerController as suggested in the PBJVideoPlayer documentation. I've commented out everything else besides creating this Video Player Controller and moving it to the parent view controller.

Comment: Jason, could you please update the status. I'm experiencing the same issue with page control performance (the UIPageViewController is complicated tablview, but it's has 0.4-0.7 second delay during swipe

Comment: @Anthony, what iOS device are you using?

Comment: @jason328 tested on iPhone 4 and iPhone 6 (doest matter). But I have located the performance issue. It was about too many complicated xib files (for custom views). I guess I have to replace xib file by views generated by code

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that was an issue of mine as well. As a side-note Snapchat also seems to have this issue on the iPhone 4S. I still have the slide issue once in awhile but with careful multithreading and limiting the views within each slide, the performance increased dramatically.